# Calculating the Euler characteristic from an instance of scipy.spatial.Delaunay

Tags: python, math, graph, scipy

## Preamble

[`scipy.spatial.Delaunay`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.Delaunay.html) provides a way of calculating the Delaunay tesselation in n dimensional space. I am interesting in calculating the Euler characteristic of the resulting graph, which entails computing the number of vertices, edges, and faces.

## Vertices

The number of vertices is easily accessed with `scipy.spatial.Delaunay().vertices.shape[0]`.

## Edges & Faces

If I recall correctly, the tesselation is composed of simplices, forming a simplicial complex. If my simplicial complex was composed of a single simplex then the number of edges would be the number of columns of `scipy.spatial.Delaunay().vertices` choose 2. And likewise there are ways of counting the number of [n-faces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Elements) (a generalized notion that I think includes edges) when there is only a single simplex. But since I have a simplicial complex, there are likely to be shared edges and faces (and n-faces)...

## Question

How can I calculate the Euler characteristic from an instance of `scipy.spatial.Delaunay`?